# Assigning Print button to screenshot not working after upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, button, gnome-screenshot

When I pressed the Print button, nothing happened.

Checked in System Settings, the button is assigned to screenshot.

If I assign ANY other button except Print, it works normally.

Is this a known bug?

HP Pavilion dv6-6051er

EDIT. Exactly as this bug but I'm using Unity not KDE: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-workspace/+bug/1243733

Apparently, no keyboard shortcuts work when assigned to the Print button. The button itself is working, as I can assign by pressing it.

Comment: Going through the linked bug report has a workaround at the end. It  boils down to 2 key codes being assigned to (Print), entering:  xmodmap -pk | grep Print  ,into a terminal window will show this.  There is also a command listed in the report to change this, however this varies depending on your machine.  After that command is issued the printscreen shortcuts can be re-assigned and should work, the only problem is this key assignment & functionality didn't survive a reboot. Work around script could be made issueing commands to reassign the keys, and the gsettings to assign printscreen.

Comment: No need for a script, just a config file, I'm writing the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, got it figured out.

The problem appears to be specific to some laptops (such as HP Pavillion dv6-6051er in my case) which use other keycodes for the Print button than the standard 107 which on desktops is both Print and Sys_Req.

Start by `xmodmap -pk | grep Print`.

In my case, it returned:

```
107     0xff61 (Print)  0xff15 (Sys_Req)    0xff61 (Print)  0xff15 (Sys_Req)    
218     0xff61 (Print)  0x0000 (NoSymbol)   0xff61 (Print)
```

So my Print button was 218 (yours can be different).

What's needed now is to assign Sys_Req to 107 so that Print is only linked with 218.

Execute `xmodmap -e "keycode 107 = Sys_Req"`.

Try to make a screenshot with Print. If fails, go System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Screenshots and re-assign the Print button to screenshots. Must be ok now.

To save the custom keyboard mapping, in the same session export current settings to an **.Xmodmap** config file, for example (saves in your home directory):

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
```

(Or you can just create an **.Xmodmap** file and only write the required tweak there, for example: `keycode 107 = Sys_Req`)

A brief **xmodmap** manual is here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap

The last step. Launch **Startup Applications** in Dash and add the following command to auto-execute **xmodmap** on login:

```
xmodmap /home/YOURUSERNAMEHERE/.Xmodmap
```

(Make sure you write the **full** path; you can alternatively auto execute smth like `xmodmap -e "keycode 107 = Sys_Req"`, too)

Over.

PS. using **xmodmap** in Unity is a bit of a hack as its native keyboard layout manager is **xbk** but it appears more difficult to tweak and documentation is lacking.

Comment: You can find another solution (this one based on xkb) here;
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1295994/comments/27